# Select2 with Vue Js as directive

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jquery-select2, vuejs2

I have been following the vue js [wrapper component example.](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/select2.html) I am trying to change how this works to allow me to add a `v-select2` directive to a regular select box rather than have to create templates and components for each one.

I have a [JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/qupexuqija/edit?html,js,output) here which shows using the component.

The component html is as follows (with the options being set in the JS).

```
  <div id="app"></div>

  <script type="text/x-template" id="demo-template">
    <div>
      <p>Selected: {{ selected }}</p>
      <select2 :options="options" v-model="selected">
        <option disabled value="0">Select one</option>
      </select2>
    
      <p>Selected: {{ selected2 }}</p>
      <select2 :options="options" v-model="selected2">
        <option disabled value="0">Select one</option>
      </select2>

      <p>Selected: {{ selected3 }}</p>
      <select2 :options="options" v-model="selected3">
        <option disabled value="0">Select one</option>
      </select2>
    </div>
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-template" id="select2-template">
    <select>
      <slot></slot>
    </select>
  </script>
```

With the JS as follows:

```
Vue.component('select2', {
  props: ['options', 'value'],
  template: '#select2-template',
  mounted: function () {
    var vm = this
    $(this.$el)
      .val(this.value)
      // init select2
      .select2({ data: this.options })
      // emit event on change.
      .on('change', function () {
        vm.$emit('input', this.value)
      })
  },
  watch: {
    value: function (value) {
      // update value
      $(this.$el).val(value)
    },
    options: function (options) {
      // update options
      $(this.$el).select2({ data: options })
    }
  },
  destroyed: function () {
    $(this.$el).off().select2('destroy')
  }
})

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '#demo-template',
  data: {
    selected: 0,
    selected2: 0,
    selected3: 0,
    options: [
      { id: 1, text: 'Hello' },
      { id: 2, text: 'World' }
    ]
  }
})
```

What I want is something like the following

```
<div id="app">

    <p>Selected: {{ selected }}</p>
    <select name="selected1" id="selected1" class="select2" v-selectize v-model="selected">
        ... options here ...
    </select>

    <p>Selected: {{ selected2 }}</p>
    <select name="selected2" id="selected2" class="select2" v-selectize v-model="selected2">
        ... options here ...
    </select>

    <p>Selected: {{ selected3 }}</p>
    <select name="selected3" id="selected3" class="select2" v-selectize v-model="selected3">
        ... options here ...
    </select>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use your component in pretty much the way you want to use your directive:

```
  <select2 name="selected1" id="selected1" v-model="selected">
    <option disabled value="0">Select one</option>
    <option value="1">Hello</option>
    <option value="2">World</option>
  </select2>
```

The `name` and `id` attributes get transferred to the underlying `select` element.

There is no (good) way to do this with a directive, which is an intentional design decision in Vue 2. There is no communication channel between a directive and the Vue as there is between a component and its parent component. A directive is not a sub-Vue, as a component is, it is a way of dealing with a small piece of the DOM in isolation.

I do not think there would be any particular advantage to writing this with a directive rather than a component.

Comment: I was trying to get it to work as a directive so I don't have to use it as a component.